# Boot Spring Application failed on sub user

Tags: linux, spring, tomcat, spring-boot

Whenever I try to run my spring boot application, my Linux machine returns me the following issue:

```
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [Connector[HTTP/1.1-80]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar!/:8.5.23]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.addConnector(StandardService.java:225) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar!/:8.5.23][...](LifecycleBase.java:150) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar!/:8.5.23]
        ... 21 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Permission denied[...]
```

> The Tomcat connector configured to listen on port 80 failed to start.
>   The port may already be in use or the connector may be misconfigured.

Hope someone can help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing you're on Ubuntu. Ports under 1024 can only be opened by `root` so as a normal unprivileged user you can't run your app on port 80. Why not use another port using `server.port` property?

Answer (score 0):

As clearly mentioned the port is already in use. Configure spring boot to use some other port.

As said in docs either set server.port as system property using command line option to jvm --server.port=8090 or add application.properties in /src/main/resources/ with

server.port = 8090
For random port use

server.port=0

Answer (score 0):

Run it as root, if Ubuntu or Debian use `Sudo your_command`. Because ports under 1024 can be used just by root.